# MySQL how to find this substring position?

Tags: mysql, substring

```
4 / 10  Used
```

This is in the middle of a bunch of other text:

```
Text text text text
 text text text text
 4 / 10  Used
text text text text
```

I'm trying to access the `4` in the above example. I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `test`
WHERE CAST(
   SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(substring(`file`, instr(`file`, '  Used') + 6, -12))), 1, 3) 
   AS SIGNED) >= 2
```

This should return the row because 4 > 2 but I this query returns nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `substring(file,1,1)` didn't work?  Oh, any mysql will do the casting for you...

Comment: @AlainCollins No it didn't. Please see my edited original post.

Comment: It looks like you always want to back up from "  Used" to the "4" and take the first character.  If so, try this: `select @foo := locate("  Used ", file), substring(file,@foo - 7,1) from test;`

Comment: @AlainCollins I'll accept that as an answer if you make it one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is my promoted comment:

It looks like you always want to back up from " Used" to the "4" and take the first character. If so, try this:

```
select @foo := locate(" Used ", file), substring(file,@foo - 7,1)
from test;
```

Comment: Thanks. Quick question, this syntax looks a bit unfamiliar to me I'm kind of new. How could you write this into a query such as `SELECT * FROM test WHERE ...`?

Comment: The "@foo :=" is setting a variable to the position.  It just keeps the `SUBSTRING` part from getting unreadable.  If you want to select other columns, you can put them at the end of the first line.